# How to map an array , and change the state asynchrony using react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want a component to re-render every 5sec and displaying the array at the corresponding indexes, the array length is known to be exactly 10.

here is what I did so far :

```
const GameCard = ({ gameArray, startGame }) => {

  const [arrayIndex, setArrayIndex] = useState(0);
  let {questionWord} = gameArray[arrayIndex] ;

  useEffect(() => {

      if(!startGame) return;

      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if(arrayIndex === 9) return; //is this valid ?
        setArrayIndex(arrayIndex +1)} , 1500)

      return () => {
          clearTimeout(timer)
      }
  }, [arrayIndex ,startGame]);

  return (<div>{questionWord}</div>)
```

`startGame` is a boolean prop that gets changed on user click.

Now, this is working but as you can see im triggering the useEffect base on 2 variables, and when i reach the end of the array I'm returning inside setTimeout preventing the arrayIndex from updating.

This feels hacky, how can I improve my async useEffect?
and what happens when we return from setTimeout function , or useEffect?

Comment: While the return value from `setTimeout`'s first argument is ignored, it's used to finish the function sooner (=> yes, it's valid). And the function returned from `useEffect` is executed before the component is unmounted and just before the same useEffect is executed again (so clearTimeout is called before a new setTimeout).

Answer (score 1):

It might be tempting to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) like `setArrayIndex((i) => i + 1)`:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState.

However, your code needs to use the original value of the `arrayIndex` constant, i.e. if it was `0` by the time `setTimeout` was registered, you want it to be `0` even after 5 seconds.

This is the case already in your code - it will be different inside different renders (each timer will have different value because it was registered inside a different render), but the value will never change between registration and execution of a timer (see [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)).

---

As for improvements, it is possible to detect the `arrayIndex === 9` even before registering a new setTimeout like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!startGame || arrayIndex >= 9) return

  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setArrayIndex(arrayIndex + 1)
  }, 5000)
  return () => clearTimeout(timer)
}, [arrayIndex, startGame])
```

Moreover, if you want the timer to discount the render time (i.e. not 5 seconds AFTER each render, but 5 second intervals), you will need a [mutable reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of an immutable state:

```
const arrayIndexRef = useRef(0)
const arrayIndex = arrayIndexRef.current
useEffect(() => {
  if(!startGame) return

  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    arrayIndexRef.current += 1
    if (arrayIndexRef.current >= 9) {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, 5000)
  return () => clearInterval(timer)
}, [startGame])
```